# How to get agent availability status in five9 using Python/Creating supervisor session

Tags: python, five9

I am trying to get the availability status (AVAILABLE_FOR_CALLS,
AVAILABLE_FOR_VMS, NOT_AVAILABLE_FOR_CALLS, etc.). I'm using five9 version 13, and according to their docs they have a method called agentState that was removed in version 10. I am using a package I found for connecting to the five9 API in python called five9, and I have used it to create an admin session. Is getting this information still possible? And if so, how. I also am having trouble using the API to create a supervisor session, though I know I have supervisor access.

```
import requests
import json
from five9 import Five9
import getpass
import zeep

username = input("username:") #input username
password = getpass.getpass('Password:') #input password
client = Five9(username, password)
```

I used `client.configuration` to create an admin session, is it possible to get the agent status information in an admin session? And I tried to use `client.supervisor` to create a supervisor session but it failed and said I don't have that permission. Is my syntax correct?